# Check string for a character loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I need to validate user input string to make sure it contains a comma.  If it does not contain a comma it must print "Error" and allow for the user to re-enter input.  I'm just not sure which loop to use.  If else may work, but I need it to loop back to the scanner for the user input. Or a while loop that uses .contains? Thanks.

Comment: You have added tags!! Try them at least once.
Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you search, you will find lots of questions on here on input validation with a loop. And yes, use [`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a loop, I recommend the for-each loop:

```
boolean found = false;
while (found == false) {
    String input = "this is a sentence, with a comma"; // read input here
    for (char ch: input.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == ',')  {
            found = true;
        } 
    }
    if (found == false) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

there will probably be functions built-in in Java for this, like "string.contains(character)" returning a boolean value

```
input.contains(",")
```

Comment: Thanks,  what if I used a while loop?  Is there an opposite of .contains?

Comment: @ANC2017 The opposite of `input.contains(",")` is `!input.contains(",")`